# What are the original forms of Mahakali,Mahalakshmi and Mahasaraswati?

Tags: lakshmi, durga, devi, kali, saraswati

According to 'Pradhanic rahasya' of Durgasaptasati, goddess Adi Shakti has three incarnations - Mahalakshmi, Mahakali, MahaSaraswati,but they are described to have four arms each which is a contradiction with the previous chapters of the book which describes them with 18,10 and 8 hands respectively.

Goddess Mahalakshmi contains in her 4 hands a fruit,club,shield,goblet.For Mahakali they are respectively shield,sword,goblet,head of a man and for  Mahasaraswati rosary,harp,goad,a book. In 'veikrutik Rahasya' of the same book we find their descriptions again with 18,10 and 8 hands respectively so,my question is what would be their actual forms ?